# Opencv 3.3.1 c++ tracking causes random crashes

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing a program which input a set of images taken by DTU's star tracker. It consist of ROI where the background is black and the stars are white. My program then have to track the stars.

The Code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\video\tracking.hpp>

#include <cmath>
#include <string>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <sstream>  
#include <filesystem> 
#include <cstring>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //Tracking of points of interest:
    cv::Mat img;
    cv::UMat prevgray;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> featuresPrevious;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> featuresCurrent;
    //int count = 0;



    for (auto& p : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator("C:\\Billeder"))
    {
        img = cv::imread(p.path().string(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        //printf("Image number: %d\n", count);
        //count++;

        if (prevgray.empty() == false)
        {
            std::vector<cv::Point2f> featuresNextPos;
            std::vector<uchar> featuresFound;
            cv::Mat err;


            featuresPrevious = std::move(featuresCurrent);
            // create points of interest in current image:
            goodFeaturesToTrack(img, featuresCurrent, 50, 0.0005, 16); //calculate the features for use in next iteration



            // Track points of interest in current image:
            calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevgray, img, featuresPrevious, featuresNextPos, featuresFound, err);
            err.release();

            //printf("featuresNextPos length: %d \n", (int)featuresNextPos.size());
            //printf("featuresfound length: %d \n", (int)featuresFound.size());
            //Draw lines connecting previous position and current position
            for (size_t i = 0; i<featuresNextPos.size(); i++) {
                if (featuresFound[i]) {

                    float dist = sqrt(pow(std::abs(featuresPrevious[i].x - featuresNextPos[i].x), 2) + pow(std::abs(featuresPrevious[i].y - featuresNextPos[i].y), 2));
                    if (dist > 15) {
                        // printf("The distance is too great to make sense \n");
                    }
                    else {
                        //Draw line from previous features to next features:
                        line(img, featuresPrevious[i], featuresNextPos[i], cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
                        if (std::abs(featuresPrevious[i].y - featuresNextPos[i].y)>9)
                        {
                            printf("Satellite might be found? Distance is: %f \n", dist);
                            //printf("Path of image containing satellite: %s \n", p.path().string());
                        }
                    }

                    //Draw the features:
                    circle(img, featuresNextPos[i], 3, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0),2);
                }
            }


        }
        else {
            printf("Go here First\n");
            goodFeaturesToTrack(img, featuresCurrent, 50, 0.005, 16); //calculate the features for use in next iteration

            //Move current image into "previous" image:
            img.copyTo(prevgray);
        }

        // Print image to show
        cv::namedWindow("Tracking Current", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Tracking Current", img);


        img.copyTo(prevgray);

        // wait for image to be printed
        cv::waitKey(10);
        //free memory again
        img.release();
    }


    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

I have been reading up on random c++ errors and for what i can understand the random crashes are due to memory not being allocated. The memory is then filled 'randomly" and if empty the code runs, and if not, the code crashes. The crashes have no apperent systematic occurences. Sometimes its at image 10 sometimes at image 200.

I suspect the function calcOpticalFlowPyrLK or goodFeaturesToTrac because i dont know how they allocate memory. I get no error message when the program crashes so i don't really have anything to go on.

Hopefully any of you overstack geniuses can help me.

regards
Ditlev

Included is two consequently images, so you get an idea with what im working with.

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i9Sk.png)
[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZnjo.png)

Comment: you should at least write the error and stack trace, to at least know in which line it is failing and to see what could be wrong.

Comment: I never get an error, the program complies just fine, and then runs for a random amount of images. I have, however, been outcommenting code, and the problem arises when i get to line calcOpticalFlowPyrLK. I'll have to look into what stack trace is. When i get it i will write it.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the error.

I created `std::vector<cv::Point2f> featuresNextPos;` and also had `std::vector<cv::Point2f> featuresCurrent;`. which are essential the same. featuesNextPos got 'created' every loop whereas featuresCurrent only got created once.

By changing the line:

`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevgray, img, featuresPrevious, featuresNextPos, featuresFound, err);`

to

`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevgray, img, featuresPrevious, featuresCurrent, featuresFound, err);`

i get no more crashes. Hopefully this was a permanent fix and not just a lucky strike. If anyone can explain why it crashes when getting created each loop feel free to comment on here.

regards
Ditlev